# while-Loop in foreach-Loop with mysqli_query leads to unexpected result

Tags: php, asynchronous, mysqli, foreach, while-loop

I have a pice of code to get data from a mysql database. I need to build containers for all stations with the same station_group which I do via a foreach loop. Inside the foreach-loop, there is a while loop to fill the station group containers with all the stations that have the parents station_group. The code works fine if I have debbugging echo lines in the code (so some kind of delay), but having them commented out, the code delivers wrong order of containers and stations. I gues its because of the asynchronous function fetch_assoc so I might put in a callback function, but I just don't get it runnig. Therefore I would appriciate any help... =)

BR

```
<?php

        //build unique Station group array
        $sql_unique = "SELECT DISTINCT station_group FROM station ORDER BY station_group ASC";
        $unique_station_groups = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql_unique);

        //get all station data
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM station ORDER BY station_group, station_id ASC";
        $result= mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql);

        //Loop for station_group
        foreach ($unique_station_groups as $station_group_value){
            echo '<div class="css-station-group>';
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                //echo "<script>console.log(".json_encode($station_group_value).")</script>";
                //echo "<script>console.log(".json_encode($row).")</script>";
                $station_id = $row['station_id'];
                $station_name = $row['station_name'];
                $station_layout = $row['station_layout'];
                $station_group = $row['station_group'];

                if ($station_group_value['station_group']==$station_group) {
                    echo '<div class="station-container css_station-layout-'.$station_layout.
                    '" id='.$station_id.
                    '>'.$station_name.
                    '<br></div>';
                }
            }
            echo '</div>';
            mysqli_data_seek($result,0); //reset array, so next Loop will find values again
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: My computer is not able to generate "`shit`", so hard to reproduce. Does it smell?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be easier to simply dump the results in an array then loop through the array.

```
<?php

        //build unique Station group array
        $sql_unique = "SELECT DISTINCT station_group FROM station ORDER BY station_group ASC";
        $unique_station_groups = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql_unique);

        //get all station data
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM station ORDER BY station_group, station_id ASC";
        $result= mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql);

        $rows = [];
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        //Loop for station_group
        foreach ($unique_station_groups as $station_group_value){
            echo '<div class="css-station-group>';
            foreach ($rows as $row) {

                //echo "<script>console.log(".json_encode($station_group_value).")</script>";
                //echo "<script>console.log(".json_encode($row).")</script>";
                $station_id = $row['station_id'];
                $station_name = $row['station_name'];
                $station_layout = $row['station_layout'];
                $station_group = $row['station_group'];

                if ($station_group_value['station_group']==$station_group) {
                    echo '<div class="station-container css_station-layout-'.$station_layout.
                    '" id='.$station_id.
                    '>'.$station_name.
                    '<br></div>';
                }
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: I was wondering about answering that way, but finally decided it wouldn't be an answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The code now deliveres the error:  "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS) in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php" at the code line "while ($rows as $row) {". I tried a foreach loop at that spot that keeps the original problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two queries to do this.

Store the previous station_group and check the current_group and previous group to differentiate the stations.

Changed your code a bit

```
<?php
    //build unique Station group array
    // $sql_unique = "SELECT DISTINCT station_group FROM station ORDER BY station_group ASC";
    // $unique_station_groups = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql_unique);

    //get all station data
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM station ORDER BY station_group ASC";
    $result= mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql);

    $rows = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    //Loop for station_group
    // foreach ($unique_station_groups as $station_group_value) {
    $current_station_group = null;
    echo '<div class="css-station-group">';
    foreach ($rows as $row) {

        //echo "<script>console.log(".json_encode($station_group_value).")</script>";
        //echo "<script>console.log(".json_encode($row).")</script>";
        $station_id = $row['station_id'];
        $station_name = $row['station_name'];
        $station_layout = $row['station_layout'];
        $station_group = $row['station_group'];

        if ($station_group != $current_station_group) {
            echo '<div class="station-container css_station-layout-'.$station_layout.
            '" id='.$station_id.
            '>'.$station_name.
            '<br></div>';
            $current_station_group = $row['station_group'];
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. One Loop is not sucifent, as it will not deliver the stations within the corresponding container.